# How do I add a parameter to a URL?

Tags: ruby, url

I'm trying to open multiple HTML documents. The URL for each site looks like this:

```
http://www.website.com/info/state=AL
```

`AL` is Alabama, but it changes by the state. I can create an array with all the two letter combinations `state=('aa'..'zz').to_a`, but how can I input this into the parameter were `AL` is above?

I want it to pull up the HTML document for all two letter combinations, and from there I can use a conditional to weed out the ones I don't want. But how should I go about inserting the two letter combinations?

Comment: By `http://www.website.com/info/state=AL` do you mean `http://www.website.com/info/?state=AL`? (Notice the `?` indicating the beginning of the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Nokogiri. It's basic String manipulation of URLs. In addition, Nokogiri doesn't open anything; File or OpenURI typically are used to open something. Finally, there are 50 states, [plus some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protectorate#United_States), compared to 676 combinations of `aa..zz`. Do you *really* want to look through 676 different possible combinations, or, instead, build a list of all the actual states plus some?

Comment: Yeah it has the ? before state, what should I do then? And yeah it'll be a little tedious as you said with all the combinations, after I create the list will I have to individually go in and set the doc (doc=Nokogiri::HTML (open("blahblahblah")) it'll parse for each output I want, or is there an easier way where I won't have to add 50+ "docs".

Comment: Adding 50 state abbreviations is a lot less tedious than having your code attempt to hit a site 626 times and getting that many 404 results, plus possibly being banned after running that multiple times. You can do a [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=state+abbreviations) to find the abbreviations and copy them into an array. From that point it's a trivial step to interpolate those into a string using `each` against the abbreviation array.

Comment: Alright thanks, I appreciate the help, you saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's URI class is useful. It's not the most full-featured package for handling URLs out there -- check out [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/tree/) if you need more, but it's good:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.website.com/info')
{
  'Alabama'    => 'AL',
  'Alaska'     => 'AK',
  'Arizona'    => 'AZ',
  'Arkansas'   => 'AR',
  'California' => 'CA',
}.each_pair do |k, v| 
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form( {'state' => v} )
  puts uri.to_s
end
```

Which outputs:

```
http://www.website.com/info?state=AL
http://www.website.com/info?state=AK
http://www.website.com/info?state=AZ
http://www.website.com/info?state=AR
http://www.website.com/info?state=CA
```

Or:

```
%w[AL AK AZ AR CA].each do |s| 
  uri.query = URI.encode_www_form( {'state' => s} )
  puts uri.to_s
end
```

Which outputs the same thing.

Comment: Thanks so much, couldn't have asked for a better answer.